# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

when it´s part of handling missing values using `SimpleImputer`, appears an error of importing related to `arpack`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

Then the issue is here

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp/ipykernel_5372/971389653.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     26 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     27 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 28 from .fixes import np_version, parse_version
     29 from ._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     30 from .validation import (

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     18 import scipy.sparse as sp
     19 import scipy
---> 20 import scipy.stats
     21 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     22 import threadpoolctl

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    439 """
    440 
--> 441 from .stats import *
    442 from .distributions import *
    443 from .morestats import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
     41 import scipy.special as special
     42 from scipy import linalg
---> 43 from . import distributions
     44 from . import mstats_basic
     45 from ._stats_mstats_common import (_find_repeats, linregress, theilslopes,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>
      6 #       instead of `git blame -Lxxx,+x`.
      7 #
----> 8 from ._distn_infrastructure import (rv_discrete, rv_continuous, rv_frozen)
      9 
     10 from . import _continuous_distns

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>
     22 # for root finding for continuous distribution ppf, and max likelihood
     23 # estimation
---> 24 from scipy import optimize
     25 
     26 # for functions of continuous distributions (e.g. moments, entropy, cdf)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py in <module>
    398 """
    399 
--> 400 from .optimize import *
    401 from ._minimize import *
    402 from ._root import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in <module>
     34                          line_search_wolfe2 as line_search,
     35                          LineSearchWarning)
---> 36 from ._numdiff import approx_derivative
     37 from scipy._lib._util import getfullargspec_no_self as _getfullargspec
     38 from scipy._lib._util import MapWrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py in <module>
      4 from numpy.linalg import norm
      5 
----> 6 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
      7 from ..sparse import issparse, csc_matrix, csr_matrix, coo_matrix, find
      8 from ._group_columns import group_dense, group_sparse

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    112 from .dsolve import *
    113 from .interface import *
--> 114 from .eigen import *
    115 from .matfuncs import *
    116 from ._onenormest import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      7 
      8 """
----> 9 from .arpack import *
     10 from .lobpcg import *
     11 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     18 
     19 """
---> 20 from .arpack import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     40 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     41 
---> 42 from . import _arpack
     43 arpack_int = _arpack.timing.nbx.dtype
     44 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a version conflict. The code you are running is expecting to find an entry point in the  DLL and is not finding it. It could be missing because the entry point the caller expects is new and the DLL is older, or because the entry point the caller expects is old and deprecated and the DLL is newer and does not have it.

Comment: Thank you very much @BoarGules now I try to uninstall the old libraries and install new ones